# Deployment/build tool between Ant and Chef

Tags: windows, testing, deployment, build

So I've been agonizing over embracing a deployment/configuration management tool like Chef or Puppet for a good long while. Not because I have any hesitation about them in general, but because I don't think they are a good fit for our specific scenario.

As far as I can see, these types of tools are targeted at frequent/wide-scale deployments, where you need to roll out software to 10s-1000s of systems. In our environment, we have a collection of ~25 different web services spread across half a dozen runtimes, with 1-8 deployments of each in production currently. Our big deployment problem is that each of the services has a different deployment story, and it's entirely manual, so it tends to be time consuming and error prone. Another wrinkle is that different instances in production may be different versions of the software, so we may need to concurrently support multiple deployment stories for a single service.

So I feel like we need something more like Ant/Maven/Rake, which is customized for each service. However, my experience with those is they are generally focused on local operations, and specific to a given language/runtime.

Is there a runtime-agnostic framework for describing and orchestrating building/testing/deployment in the manner I'm interested in?

I'm sure if I hit them long enough, I could get Rake or Puppet to do these for me, but I'm looking for something built for this purpose.

(Oh, and to make things worse, everything runs on Windows)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative you might want to consider: [kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net) (I'm affiliated) is a free lightweight deploiement tool which besides having a web management interface can also integrate with ant (or maven or anything else with python CLI) to automate build & deploiement on dev/test environments for instance.

One of the nice things is the web configuration interface which make it pretty easy to quickly configure your deploiment stories, i.e. which software/version goes on which server. It's often necessary to setup different parameters in configuration files depending on the target server. For that you can "templatize" your packages using kwatee variable (similar to environment variables) which are configured with different values for each server.

Software must be registered in Kwatee's repository in the form of a folder of files, or an archive (zip, tar, tar.gz, bzip2, war) or a single file (e.g. an exe). Msi's are not supported. To deploy on windows kwatee needs the servers to have either telnet/ftp or ssh/scp (there are free tools out there).

Comment: Thanks mac, will definitely take a look!